# How change the standard form format of double.ToString();

Tags: c#, tostring

the following code:

```
double number = 85047564288067.5
string numberString = number.toString("G3");
Console.WriteLine(numberString);
```

will print: `8.5E+13`

which obviously is correct but is there a way for the `toString()` function to return numbers that are in standard form in the format: `8.5x10^13`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just replace `E` with `x10^`:

```
string numberString = number.ToString("G3", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
                            .Replace("E", "x10^").Replace("+", "");
```

Comment: On my German machine this returns `8,5x10^13` (mind the comma)

Comment: @marsze that's because the separator is different in your culture

Comment: @RuiJarimba Of course it is and that's why you have to take that into account!

Comment: @marsze my point is that the OP is concerned with the exponent part of the number/output, not with the decimal or thousands separator

Comment: @Adrian I just ran a test, it should be `.Replace("E", "x10^")` instead of `.Replace("e", "x10^")`

Answer (score 0):

If it's just for display purposes, then this should do the job.

```
    double number = 85047564288067.5;
    string numberString = number.ToString("G3").Replace("E+","x10^");
    Console.WriteLine(numberString);
```

Comment: I should note that this wont work on negatives, another answer below covers negatives.

Comment: I don't know why this answer was downvoted, it seems to work fine - even with negatives. The output is the same as the accepted answer.

Comment: @RuiJarimba It does not work with negative exponents, that's the issue

Comment: @Adrian got it :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use it more effectively as follows

**Extension Method**

```
 public static class DoubleExtension
      {
            public static string ToString10Th(this double p)
            {            
               return p.ToString("0.#E+0", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Replace("E-", "x10^-").Replace("E+", "x10^");            
            }
      }
```

**Usage**

```
    double number = 85047564288067.5;
    Console.WriteLine(number.ToString10Th());
```

Answer (score -1):

Try with [exponential notation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings).
Maybe something like this:

```
double number = 85047564288067.5
string numberString = string.Format("{0:0.#E+00}", number);
Console.WriteLine(numberString);
```

Comment: This is not what the OP is asking for.... Your output is `8.505E+13`, not `8.505x10^13`